# Excel: index & match formula issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I'm trying to use index & match formula but every time the message came out that I've a problem with this formula as attached picture..
simply, I need the to display the name of the highest score in the picture

I used the formula

```
=Index(B11:F11,MATCH(I11;B12:F12;0))
```

what is wrong ?
please help :)

Answer (score 1):

I've sotted 2 possible issues.

1. the formula in the image is actually `=INDEX(B11:F11,+MATCH(I11;B12:F12;0))`
2. you are using both , and ; as seperators use one or the other.

Try :

```
=INDEX(B11:F11,MATCH(I11,B12:F12,0))
```

Or

```
=INDEX(B11:F11;MATCH(I11;B12:F12;0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`PeterH` has certainly hit on an important part! To my knowledge, Excel uses one approach or the other, but no mixture of both (so only commas or only semi-colons).

However, there is another issue. You have set up your `INDEX/MATCH` in the standard manner... but the standard manner is to use it to look u a ROW and return all columns in it, or one, or several (to be technical, even more possibilities exist). If desiring all columns, one leaves that third parameter blank, as you do here.

You want a COLUMN though, not a row. So you need to use the `MATCH()` portion in the THIRD parameter and that means you have to do something in the second parameter's place. Simply putting a comma (or semi-colon) there would be fine, or a zero-comma (`0,`) (or zero-semi-colon, `0;`):

```
=INDEX(B11:F11,,MATCH(I11,B12:F12,0))
=INDEX(B11:F11,0,MATCH(I11,B12:F12,0))

=INDEX(B11:F11;;MATCH(I11;B12:F12;0))
=INDEX(B11:F11;0;MATCH(I11;B12:F12;0))
```

Then all should work nicely.

Comment: Actually that's not correct. When INDEXing a single row it's not necessary to use the third parameter. So `INDEX(B11:F11,MATCH(I11,B12:F12,0))`, with the `MATCH` construction occupying the second parameter of `INDEX`, not the third, is perfectly acceptable